# Replace whole DOM in javascript

Tags: javascript, dom, replace, undo

I need to implement undo-redo functionality in my project. But it is very complex and every change affects on many elements. I think saving and restoring whole page will be the best choice. But i have some problems with missing .data() params of DOM elements. I use next functions:

```
// save
var documentCopy = document.documentElement.cloneNode(true);

// restore
document.replaceChild(
documentCopy,
document.documentElement
);
```

How I can save and restore whole DOM with saving jQuery.data() of elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trivial thing that I would try is using jQuery's [`clone`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) instead. Be sure to use it with two `true` parameters, but be careful as this may be very very slow. Are you sure this is the only way to achieve what you want? Can't you replace a smaller portion of the document?

Note that this doesn't seem to work well with `document.documentElement`, and that using it with the document's `body` seems to lose the data on the original elements (say what?). [Here's a small test.](http://jsfiddle.net/hfWC3/)